# How to ignore a searchcomponent in searchhandler components in Solr

Tags: apache, solr, solrj

I have a config defined as follows:

```
    <requestHandler name="/search" class="org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler">
     <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="spellcheck">true</str>
         .
         .
         .
    </lst>
    <arr name="components">
      <str>search</str>
      <str>search_custom_response_builder</str>
    </arr>
  </requestHandler>
```

Now, when I perform queries, I want the both search and search_custom_response_builder to be executed but for testing purposes, I want to see the output of only search. How can I achieve this? I know it's trivial using another Requesthandler, but I am wondering if there is a better way. Is there? Can I somehow tell Solr to only get results from search and not search_custom_response_builder?

Comment: I've never tried this before, but I think the only way you can accomplish what you want is to do something via the Config API. You can read up about it here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Config+API. With the Config API I think you could dynamically add and remove components, depending on whether you're testing or not. Some Googling tells me that SolrJ may or may not have support for the Config API, so you might have to handle calls to that API outside of SolrJ.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the standard examples, you can see that search components have an enable flag, for example:

```
<!-- Clustering Component

   You'll need to set the solr.clustering.enabled system property
   when running solr to run with clustering enabled:

        java -Dsolr.clustering.enabled=true -jar start.jar

   http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ClusteringComponent
   http://carrot2.github.io/solr-integration-strategies/
-->
<searchComponent name="clustering"
               enable="${solr.clustering.enabled:false}"
               class="solr.clustering.ClusteringComponent" >
```

So you can pass that as a parameter with the startup scripts. I also believe you might be able to [specify that in the core.properies file](http://Configuringsolrconfig.xml-Userdefinedpropertiesfromcore.properties):

If you have a recent 5.x Solr, you could also look into [Request Parameters and/or useParams](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Request+Parameters+API), though I am not sure the components block is supported in that (it should). In the case of useParams, the additional parameters become another variable in the URL.